# Why UITableViewCell shrinks contentView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

Here is the `UITableView` that I want to make:

[image]

In order to achieve this, I divided `contentView` of cell into three parts.

1 - *fromView*: contains start time and class type. Height will be 30% of *contentView*

2 - *infoView*: contains clock image, class name and professor's name. Height will be 40% of `contentView`.

3 - *toView*: contains end time and location. Height will be space that left(30%).

Firstly, before going to details, I decided to show this containers only. For understanding a problem, I painted them(green, red, blue respectively).

After adding them into the `contentView`, here are the constraints I gave to those containers:

```
   fromView.easy.layout(Top(), Left(), Right(), Height(*0.3).like(contentView))

    infoView.easy.layout(Top().to(fromView), Left(), Right(), Height(*0.4).like(contentView))

    toView.easy.layout(Top().to(infoView), Left(), Right(), Bottom())
```

Seems like everything is right. After launching, I thought that I will see them, but here is what happened:

[image]

I thought that cell does not know what size it needs to be, so I decided to implement following function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}
```

After this, `UITableView` showed containers pretty correctly than before. But, I plan to add some `UILabel`s and other `views` into that containers(look at first picture). In other words, I don't know what size a cell needs to have. It needs to be kind of dynamic. Anyway, I tried to add those labels into the containers, maybe after that, a cell will figure out the the height. Here is how I did it:

```
func setupViews() {

    fromView.addSubviews(fromTime, classType)

    toView.addSubviews(toTime, room)

    infoView.addSubviews(clockImage, teacherName, subjectName)

    contentView.addSubviews(toView, fromView, infoView)



}

func setupConstraints() {

    fromView.easy.layout(Top(), Left(), Right(), Height(*0.3).like(contentView))

    infoView.easy.layout(Top().to(fromView), Left(), Right(), Height(*0.4).like(contentView))

    toView.easy.layout(Top().to(infoView), Left(), Right(), Bottom())

    fromTime.easy.layout(CenterY(), Left(8))

    fromTime.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    fromTime.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    classType.easy.layout(CenterY(), Left(8).to(fromTime))

    clockImage.easy.layout(CenterY(), Left(16), Width(24), Height(24))

    subjectName.easy.layout(CenterY(-8), Left().to(classType, .left), Right())

    teacherName.easy.layout(Top(8).to(subjectName), Left().to(subjectName, .left), Right())


    toTime.easy.layout(CenterY(), Left(8))

    toTime.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    toTime.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)


    room.easy.layout(CenterY(), Left(8).to(toTime))

}
```

But anyway, problem appeared again like this:

[image]

I think, the problem is that I give height to containers according to height of `contentView`, but `contentView` does not know its height. But I also don't know what height it needs to have, cause it needs to depend according to size of labels. So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set heights for the containers. You have to make sure the top and bottom of the cell are connected through constraints. My recommendation is to just get rid of the containers, add all the labels and images to the cell directly, and create constraints like this.

[image]

Then set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`, or return `UITableView.automaticDimension` from `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is good idea to remove containers. But, look at label that shows '800'. It needs to be below `professor's name` and also it needs to be horizontally along with timeLabel that shows `12:00`. This is the reason why I used containers. I thought that containers help me to solve this problem. How can it be achieved via using constraints only? In the picture you showed only vertical constraints.

Comment: You can use constraints to center labels vertically. For example you can add a constraint to align the baselines of the `12:00` and `800` label. You can also add a constraint to vertically align the centers (Y center) of the `11:30` and `practice` labels. Etc.

Comment: I decided to use your approach. But, I am sure that AutoLayout can allow me to achieve such a result. Look at `800` label and `12:00` label. They need to be in one horizontal line. In other words, I set to `800` label a constraint like `CenterY().to(12:00)`. We set constraint in vertical axis, but AutoLayout demands from us also in horizontal axis. For this, I set to `800` label a constraint like `Left().to(professorName, .left)`. But, also, we didn't consider one detail. Now, `800` depends on `12:00` in vertical axis, but `professor's name` can be long. So if it is, it just overlaps `800`.

Comment: You can 100% achieve this layout without overlapping. You should pin the 800 to the bottom of the professor’s name, and then align the 12:00 to the 800. That way the 800 will go down as much as needed to make room for the professor’s name, and the 12:00 will always be next to it.

Comment: The last question is about UIImageView(clock's image). It needs to be vertically centered in the cell. This requirement breaks your idea, cause you wrote that 12:00 needs to be aligned with 800, but it also doesn't have to overlap with clock image. So, what constraint a clock image needs to have?

Answer (score 1):

Try by giving height constraint to your main view inside your cell.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You mean, giving height constraint to contentView? But, as I've said in question, I don't know its exact height. It needs to depend on content of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Look like what you want is a dynamic height calculated based on the content's AutoLayout. Update the delegates to return the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the `heightForRowAt` and some good estimation, e.g., 150 for the `estimatedHeightForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Then you can just set the content's size using autolayout, and the table will calculate the height of the cells for you dynamically.

Estimated height is used for scrolling purposes - a good estimate will provide you a good scrolling experience (dynamic height is calculated only when the cell is being displayed, thus for the yet undisplayed cells the `tableView` will use estimation when scrolling).

Comment: I added constraint to `contentView` like this:  `contentView.easy.layout(Top(), Left(), Right(), Height(150))`

Also I used above codes to add estimated height. But, does your suggestion really guarantees that cell will show all data inside it? I mean, it has information only about estimated height, and you mean that if intrinsic content size of labels will be bigger, cell will figure out height for itself?

Comment: @abay I dont think you need to set constraints explicitly for the `contentView` - it is enough if its contenthas explicit constraints that tell the cell how the content relates to the `contentView`. e.g., you put a `view1` as a subview of the `contentView`, then constrain it's top, left, right, and bottom anchors to top, left, right, and bottom anchors of the `contentView`, respectively. That would tell the cell, that the `contentView` should be as large as `view1`, and vice versa. Now if you add a constraint saying that `view1.height` is 100, that would tell the cell that `contentView.height`

Comment: is also 100 points high. Now if you set automatic cell height, this will be used when the cell is presented. If you use explicit height, e.g., 150, this will cause collisions between the cell height and constraints.